# getting an error while using JDA in android

Tags: discord-jda

Basically i'm planing to make a music bot android application,but i'm getting the following error.

Here is the error i'm getting

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.jdabot, PID: 18944
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.utils.Checks.notNull(Checks.java:68)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.api.requests.GatewayIntent.getRaw(GatewayIntent.java:255)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.api.requests.GatewayIntent.<clinit>(GatewayIntent.java:169)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDABuilder.<clinit>(JDABuilder.java:58)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDABuilder.createLight(JDABuilder.java:241)
    at com.example.jdabot.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:21)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
    at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)"
```

> I have no idea why am i getting this error can any one help me out.
> My code is below

JDA jda;

```
{
    try {
        jda = JDABuilder.createLight("token").build();
    } catch (LoginException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

> no matter whatever i try the output result is same.

Comment: Do you maybe have a little more code to work with? This doesn't give us enough information on what the error could be caused by

Comment: We would need some more code to help fix your issue. Please provide your whole "MainActivity" Class.